# Url of Return View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, friendly-url

In the context of this question [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/asp-net-mvc-friendly-url) is possible from a Controller that responds to a Form Post to go to the Friendly Url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Your controller action can determine the friendly url based on how you would like the route defined for it, then do a Redirect to the friendly url instead of returning the view.  It will cause another browser request which will add load to to your server, so you'd want to be sure that it was really important.

Comment: Which -- finding the friendly url or doing the redirect?  Constructing the friendly url and the controller action to handle it is really a matter of you deciding how.  Doing the redirect is just constructing a RedirectResult with the appropriate url.

Comment: I already have the friendly url so the RedirectResult, thanks

Comment: The way is RedirectToAction("action","controller",parameters)