# Create short permalinks similar to Stack Overflow's "short permalink to this question"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, permalinks, response.redirect, short-url

I think I might already understand how this works, but wanted to be sure.

I am in the process of defining the routes for a new ASP.NET MVC application. I'd like to create short permalinks similar to Stack Overflow's *short permalink to this question*:

> [Create short permalinks similar to Stack Overflow's "short permalink to this question"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4047890/61654)

What route and controller mechanism is Stack Overflow using for this permalink behavior?

Other Questions discussing Stack Overflow question routes:

- [How can I create a friendly URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/217960/61654)
- [How do you include a webpage title as part of a webpage URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25259/61654)
- [Creating search engine friendly URL's in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1148955/61654)

Comment: yes that's basically it. Also this isn't really asked in Q&A format -- you should answer your question with some of the above text.

Comment: @Jeff agreed, on the question format. I'll rework it around an answer. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @Jeff split up into a question and answer. Thanks again for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the Stack Overflow routes are setup something similar to this:

```
routes.MapRoute("question-permalink", "q/{questionId}/{userId}", 
    new { controller = "PermaLinkController",
        action = "Question", userId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { questionId = "[0-9]+", userId = "[0-9]+" });
```

Based on the `302 Found` pointing to the question's current location: I assume the PermaLink controller's Question action looks something like this:

```
public class PermaLinkController : Controller
{
    public Question (int questionId, int? userId)
    {
        // do work to record userId that shared link
        // ...
        // now redirect
        Response.RedirectToRoute("question", new { questionId = questionId });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is pulled out from an original version of the above question. It's marked as the answer per Jeff's comment on the question.