# passing multiple parameter in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

I have an controller that takes 3 paramteres

```
public ActionResult Directives(string MachineName, int ProjectId, int CompanyId)
```

Right now the Url looks like this.

```
/Project/Directives?projectId=41&MachineName=Apple%20Macbook%20Luft
```

But how do i get it to look like this.

```
/Project/Directives/41/AppleMacbookAir/
```

Comment: This quiestion might help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/how-can-i-create-a-friendly-url-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: If you have a route that handles the pattern registered, your URLs will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Project",                                              // Route name
     "{Controller}/{Action}/{projectId}/{machineName}/{companyId}",                           
     new { controller = "Project", action = "Directives", projectId = 0, machineName = "", companyId = 0 }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: It works perfectly. But i cant get the ´return RedirectToAction("Directives", "Project", new { MachineName = project.MachineName, ProjectId = projectId, CompanyId = user.Company_Id });` To give me the right value? It's still the /Dire.../Project=23&CompanyId=27....

Comment: Try `return RedirectToAction("Directives", "Project", new { projectId = projectId, machineName = project.MachineName, CompanyId = user.Company_Id });` You need to have the params in the correct order perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id as part of the routeValues parameter of the `RedirectToAction()` method.

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", new { id = 99 });
```

This will cause a redirect to `Site/Controller/Action/99.`

**Edit:** 
For customizing url, you have to create `custom route` as:

```
routes.MapRoute(  "Project", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{Action}/{ProjectId}/{MachineName}/{CompanyId}", 
                   new { controller = "Project", 
                         action = "Directives", 
                         ProjectId= 0,
                         MachineName= "",
                         CompanyId = 0 
                       }  // Parameter defaults );
```

Use `UrlParameter.Optional` if you want any parameter optional.
Follow By Stephen Walthe article on [ASP.NET MVC Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Refer this: [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter/1257632#1257632)