# ASP.Net mvc2 url format issue

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-mvc-2, maproute

In my mvc2 project, some URL are shown in the browser like this,

> localhost:53289/Paper/ViewAgendaPaper?MeetingId=186&type=2&RefId=186

but i prefer to look it like this,

> localhost:53289/Paper/ViewAgendaPaper

In my Global.asax,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

How to hide the id fields in the URL. Please give me some idea. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I think you can't hide the Ids as they are supposed to be passed to fetch the exact data, however instead of

```
localhost:53289/Paper/ViewAgendaPaper?MeetingId=186&type=2&RefId=186
```

you can have it like:

```
localhost:53289/Paper/ViewAgendaPaper/186/2/186
```

Going through this post will help you more:
[How can I create a friendly URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/how-can-i-create-a-friendly-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The place where you are making the above link, simply change it and make it to appear like the one i told you and things will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are asking for with a simple link. An anchor link `<a>...</a>` performs a simple GET. If you want to hide the parameters, you would need to do a POST to the page in question.