# make url shorter of some controllers and actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to make some urls of my asp.net MVC4 app shorter. For example I have `Account` controller and such action `ForgotPassword`. Url looks like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com/account/forgotpassword
```

I would like to make the url shorter(example below) without renaming actual controller and action names. What is the best way to do that?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/a/fp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register a simple route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ForgottenPassword",
   url: "a/fp",
   defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ForgottenPassword" }
);
```

...in RouteConfig.cs if you're using MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, then your talking about Friendly URL's?

Please have a look @ [quysnhat.wordpress.com](http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/seo-friendly-urls-in-asp-net-mvc/)

There was a very nice [post in Hanselman's web](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

Also, there were few questions related to friendly url's(in case it helps you) :-

[How can I create a friendly URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/how-can-i-create-a-friendly-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/10/function-to-generate-a-url-friendly-string.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest but not the best way of doing it is to hand-code your custom routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "AccountForgotRoute",
    url: "a/fp/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "ForgotPassword", id = UrlParameter.Optional }        
);
```

The downside to that is if you will have tons of controllers and action methods and you like all of them to be "shortened", then you will have to write a lot of routes.

One alternative is to define your custom routes in a database and write it out on a file. So for example you have in a database row an `accountcontroller-forgotpassword` key with a value of `a/fp`, you dynamically build the route definition, write it in a file and let your application pick it up. How your application can pick up the route definition can be done like [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx). That link is still applicable for MVC 4. But this one is really messy, IMO, but is an alternative.