# How do I generically implement URL-rewriting in a MapRoute method?

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am attempting to rewrite URL's from C#'s Pascal-case to SEO-friendly format.

For example, I want something like `/User/Home/MyJumbledPageName` to look like this:

```
/user/home/my-jumbled-page-name // lower-case, and words separated by dashes
```

Here is my method for converting each "token" in the URL:

```
public static string GetSEOFriendlyToken(string token)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0, len = token.Length; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            // setting the first capital char to lower-case:
            str.Append(Char.ToLower(token[i]));
        }
        else if (Char.IsUpper(token[i]))
        {
            // setting any other capital char to lower-case, preceded by a dash:
            str.Append("-" + Char.ToLower(token[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            str.Append(token[i]);
        }
    }
    return str.ToString();
}
```

...and in my `RouteConfig.cs` file in the root, I have mapped these routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // without this the first URL is blank:
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default_Home",
        url: "index", // hard-coded?? it works...
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Home",
        // the method calls here do not seem to have any effect:
        url: GetSEOFriendlyToken("{action}") + "/" + GetSEOFriendlyToken("{id}"),
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

With this code, a URL such as `/AboutTheAuthor` is **not** converted to what I want, which would be `/about-the-author`.

It seems that my method call is ignored, what's happening here? And what's the conventional way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your own `RouteBase` class or subclass `Route`

```
public class SeoFriendlyRoute : Route
{
    private readonly string[] _valuesToSeo;

    public SeoFriendlyRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IEnumerable<string> valuesToSeo, RouteValueDictionary constraints = null, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens = null, IRouteHandler routeHandler = null)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints ?? new RouteValueDictionary(), dataTokens ?? new RouteValueDictionary(), routeHandler ?? new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        if (valuesToSeo == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valuesToSeo"); }
        _valuesToSeo = valuesToSeo.ToArray();
    }
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (routeData != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in _valuesToSeo)
            {
                if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    routeData.Values[key] = GetActualValue((string)routeData.Values[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return routeData;
    }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        var seoFriendyValues = new RouteValueDictionary(values);
        foreach (var key in _valuesToSeo)
        {
            if (seoFriendyValues.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                seoFriendyValues[key] = GetSeoFriendlyValue((string)seoFriendyValues[key]);
            }
        }
        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, seoFriendyValues);
    }

    private string GetSeoFriendlyValue(string actualValue)
    {
        //your method
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0, len = actualValue.Length; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                str.Append(Char.ToLower(actualValue[i]));
            }
            else if (Char.IsUpper(actualValue[i]))
            {
                str.Append("-" + Char.ToLower(actualValue[i]));
            }
            else
            {
                str.Append(actualValue[i]);
            }
        }
        return str.ToString();
    }

    private static string GetActualValue(string seoFriendlyValue)
    {
        //action name is not case sensitive
        //one limitation is the dash can be anywhere but the action will still be resolved
        // /my-jumbled-page-name is same as /myjumbled-pagename
        return seoFriendlyValue.Replace("-", string.Empty); 
    }
}
```

Usage

```
routes.Add("Default", new SeoFriendlyRoute(
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    valuesToSeo: new string[] { "action", "controller" },
    defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }))
);
```

Comment: Thanks @LostInComputer! This is a bit further down the rabbit-hole for me, so I have been researching your code. I learned that you are using the "null coalescing operator" `??`, in which is shorthand for the ternary operator. Also I see that you are using the constructor parameters required for invoking `base` on `Route`, found by in Visual Studio by right-clicking on `Route` and selecting "Peek Definition". Otherwise, how do you know to override `GetRouteData` and `GetVirtualPath`? Where in the framework do these methods get invoked?

Comment: Other questions I have are is the `GetActualValue` method a requirement for this logic, and where is a good place to put this class in a project?

Comment: `GetVirtualPath` is called by MVC to generate the URL like when you call `@Html.Action`. `GetRouteData` is the reverse, its called by MVC to get the controller action from the URL. How did I know? I would sometimes go thru the MVC source code which is open source.

Comment: Ok so I now see that the `GetActualValue` method *is* a requirement -- the overridden `GetRouteData` method needs for any "subdirectory" token to be *without* dashes so that MVC can find the corresponding controller and/or action in the `RouteData`. Also, MVC matches such "subdirectory" strings case-insensitive, as per the comments in the code state.

Comment: Yes. I kind of cheated though since `GetActualValue` just removes all dashes no matter the location so `/index-dash`, `/indexd-ash` and `/indexdash` all get routed to the same action.

Comment: Thanks @LostInComputer, here is a case where the dashes could be a problem -- if there were two actions named something like `MyPageName` and `MyPagename`, which would then be rewritten as `my-page-name` and `my-pagename`, the overridden `GetRouteData` could register the same action for both pages. I will just make sure to use dissimilar names for pages then ;)

Comment: Also for reference, I now see that this class could be placed anywhere in the project because it is `public`. So, I have placed this in a folder I created in the root named "Utility".

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I have found how to make @LostInComputer 's code work for areas as well. The class used for an area must implement `IRouteWithArea` for `context.Routes.Add` to work in an area's `RegisterArea` method.

Here's a generic class that can be used for areas (it extends the above `SEOFriendlyRoute` class):

```
public class AreaSEOFriendlyRoute : SEOFriendlyRoute, IRouteWithArea
{
    private readonly string _areaName;

    // constructor:
    public AreaSEOFriendlyRoute(string areaName, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IEnumerable<string> valuesToSeo,
        RouteValueDictionary constraints = null, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens = null, IRouteHandler routeHandler = null)
        : base(url, defaults, valuesToSeo, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler)
    {
        this._areaName = areaName;
    }

    // implemented from IRouteWithArea:
    public string Area
    {
        get
        {
            return this._areaName;
        }
    }
}
```

...and its' usage:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.Routes.Add("Example", new AreaSEOFriendlyRoute(
        areaName: this.AreaName,
        url: "my-area/{action}/{id}",
        valuesToSeo: new string[] { "action", "controller" },
        defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyDefaultPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }))
    );
}
```

Note that I am passing an extra argument when calling `context.Routes.Add`, which is defined as `areaName`. The formal parameter of the same name in the constructor is used to return this value from the `Area` method, in which is implemented from `IRouteWithArea`.

---

So a link such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("my link text", "MyJumbledPageName", "MyController",
new { area = "MyArea" }, null)
```

...would result in the url `my-area/my-jumbled-page-name`. Also note that the preceding "`my-area`" in the url is obtained by hard-coding this in the route's `url` argument.