# UrlHelper.Action not generating pretty url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, pretty-urls

I'm generating SEO-friendly "Pretty URLs" using this custom route, inspired by [posts here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20662188/337103):

```
// Route used for Details view
routes.Add("CarDetailsRoute", new SeoFriendlyRoute(
    url: "car/{state}/{community}/{make}/{model}/{slug}-{id}",
    valuesToSeo: new string[] { "state", "community", "make", "model", "slug" },
    defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Vehicle", action = "Details", slug = UrlParameter.Optional, state = UrlParameter.Optional, community = UrlParameter.Optional, make = UrlParameter.Optional, model = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    constraints: new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = @"\d+" })
));

/// The interesting route
routes.Add("CarIndexRoute", new SeoFriendlyRoute(
    url: "car/{state}/{community}/{make}/{model}/",
    valuesToSeo: new string[] { "state", "community", "make", "model" },
    defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Vehicle", action = "Index", state = UrlParameter.Optional, community = UrlParameter.Optional, make = UrlParameter.Optional, model = UrlParameter.Optional })
));

// Unrelated routes

// Fallback default route
routes.Add("Default", new SeoFriendlyRoute(
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    valuesToSeo: new string[] { "action", "controller" },
    defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }))
);
```

However, when I'm generating the breadcrumbs from my Details view to generate generic searches on parts of the details information, somehow the custom route fails and the default route kicks in.

```
// RequestContext here being a full qualified with Make, Model, Community
// and State. These are inserted in to all .Action()s by default, so i have
// to "remove them" where I don't want them.
var url = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext); 
var breadcrumbs = new List<IBreadcrumbLink>() {
    new BreadcrumbLink() {
        Title = vehicle.Dealer.State,
        Url = url.Action("Index", new { model = string.Empty, make = string.Empty, community = string.Empty })
        // Doesn't work, generates ~/vehicle/?model=aaa&make=bbb&community=ccc&state=ddd
        // Expected ~/car/state/
    }, 
    new BreadcrumbLink() {
        Title = vehicle.Dealer.Community,
        Url = url.Action("Index", new { model = string.Empty, make = string.Empty })
        // Works, generates ~/car/state/community/
    }, 
    new BreadcrumbLink(){
        Title = vehicle.Make,
        Url = url.Action("Index", new { model = string.Empty })
        // Works, generates ~/car/state/community/make/
    },
    new BreadcrumbLink(){
        Title = vehicle.Model,
        Url = url.Action("Index")
        // Works, generates ~/car/state/community/make/model/
    }
};
```

What would cause this behavior? Visiting the expected url of `~/car/state/` works like a charm, but as stated I cannot generate this url?

Comment: What other routes do you have defined and in what order are they in the rout config?

Comment: Hi @DavidG, updated my question! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you use `model = UrlParameter.Optional` instead of using `string.Empty`?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. This first caused a casting error in SeoFriendlyRoute, but after resolving that I get `~/vehicle?community=&make=&model=` instead.