# how to create hierarchy of pages in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a classified website that will have links like "electronics/mobiles/samsung/samsungS3/adTitle". How to create hierarchy of views like that in asp.net. If the answer is HMVC then please refer some link that contains complete guide how to implement HMVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need hierarchy of Views, you should use [Route Config](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) that will allow you to get View that you need base on URL.

From 4 Version of MVC also have [areas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) not only controlles and View by default. So check this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC) to know how to customise your Routing.

Comment: Thanks but what i want is that there should be separate query for each link like if link ends with "mobiles" it will show all ads in mobiles and if it ends with "samsung" it will show all mobile ads of samsung and so on

Comment: @IrfanWattoo you talking about controller params and you can use them in routing, like `id = UrlParameter.Optional` in default example, you can make something like `brand = UrlParameter.Optional` and use it in your controller like param that helps you to show right ad.

Comment: there will be only one view to display all types of ads but query will be different

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create views in this hierarchy but you need to create URLs in this fashion and that is called friendly URLs.

Look at following stack overflow question
[How can I create a friendly URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/how-can-i-create-a-friendly-url-in-asp-net-mvc) and [Friendly URL](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/friendly-urls)

---

You will be defining another route which will end up on your single action method. So You will add a route in routeConfig.cs as follows

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "custom",
                url: "{category}/{type}/{manufacturer}/{version}/{Title}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "customRoute"}
            );
```

and your custom action will have all values passed in as param be as follows

```
public string customRoute(string category, string type, string manufacturer, string version, string Title)
{
    return category + type + manufacturer + version + Title;
}
```

You can achieve the same using action based routing as well

```
 // eg: electronics/mobiles/samsung/samsungS3/adTitle
    [Route("{category}/{type}/{manufacturer}/{Title}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string cateogry, string type,string manfacture, string Title) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks haseeb but i don't want to make friendly URL. There should be separate query for each link like if link ends at "mobiles" it will show all ads in mobiles and if it ends with "samsung" it will show all mobile ads of samsung and so on.

Comment: You can achieve that as well using this approach. Creating separate folder for each mobile manufacturer isn't scale-able (Extendible) because you will required to add new vendors every now and then.

Comment: there will be only one view to display ads but query will be different. This is what i wanted